# Update same table by its maximum date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in which i have to find the maximum date for each unique EMPid & testid

below is the input table and expected output

[image]

I tried with correlated sub query but that didn't work.

Any quick way to update the table with max date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [common-table-expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and the [`OVER` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) with `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT EmpId, [Hall Id], testId, Date, [Max date],
           MaxDate = MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, testId)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
UPDATE CTE SET [Max date] = MaxDate
```

If you want to see what will happen replace `UPDATE` with `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: One small question, I am able to update CTE but how can i update my actual table now ? i.e. dbo.TableName

Comment: I think I can not access CTE more than once

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: My query above already updates `TableName`. Understand a cte as a sub-query to the original table. If the cte selects **only one table** you can use `UPDATE` or `DELETE` firectly as if you would do it on the table directly. Otherwise you need to join the cte with the table you want to update/delete as Aquillo has shown.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: Why do you want to access it more than once? If you want to see the result of your update _before_ you update, change the `UPDATE` to `SELECT` and you'll see it. If you want to see the result _after_ you've updated use `SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to select all maximum dates and join this with your original data like this:

```
WITH MaxDates AS (
    SELECT      empid
                , testid
                , MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
    FROM        table
    GROUP BY    empid
                , testid
)

SELECT          table.*
                , MaxDate
FROM            table
INNER JOIN      MaxDates ON table.empid = MaxDates.empid AND table.testid = MaxDates.testid
```